# Seemingly Unrelated regression with Truncated data

Tags: regression, econometrics, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

I have sales data (quantity sold (tons) and the prices that those forest products were sold ($/ton)) of three forest products (e.g., sawtimber, chip-and-saw and pulpwood) and sales of these products were done by individual forest owners. Considering the fact that these three forest products can come from a single tree harvest (cut), so their quantity are related - large quantity of one product sale might lead to small quantity of other two products sale.

Thus, I am assuming Seemingly unrelated regression (SUR) model will fit this data type to understand relationship between quantity (y) of these forest products and price of the forest products (x). If not, please let me know what would be a better model. So, my main question is, if SUR model is correct, do I have to run a truncated SUR model - because I only have data of forest products that were sold by forest owners. There are forest products that are not sold (or unharvested or uncut) by forest owners that exists in the forest, which I have no information of quantity and since they were not sold, the price of these unsold products does not exist.

Please let me know what method/model will be right fit for these kind of data. In addition, if truncated seemingly unrelated regression (I don't know if this is the correct terminology) is what I am supposed to do, what does the procedure of this regression look like and how can I do it in R?